# Tensorflow: create a tf.constant from a tf.Variable

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to optimize a cost function. This cost function contains variables and other parameters that are not variables. This non-variable parameters are obtained from the variables.

Here is a toy example that illustrates the point:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

r_init = np.array([5.0,6.0])

x = tf.get_variable("x_var", initializer = r_init[0], trainable = True)
y = tf.get_variable("y_var", initializer = r_init[1], trainable = True)

def cost(x,y):
    a = x
    return a*((x-1.0)**2+(y-1.0)**2)

train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.05).minimize(cost(x,y))

with tf.Session() as sess:

        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for i in range(100):
            print(sess.run([cost(x,y), train_op]))
            print('x=', x.eval(session=sess))
            print('y=', y.eval(session=sess))
```

As you can see, the parameter `a` is defined from the variable `x`, on the other hand `a` should not be a variable, I want the optimizer to see it as a constant. This constant should be updated as the variable `x` is updated in the optimization process.

How can I define a non-variable parameter `a` from the variable `x`? I am making this up, but intuitively, what comes to my mind is something like:

```
a = tf.to_constant(x)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `a` is `x`. Tensorflow did not create a new variable here. Lets consider a more complex situation. `z = x + y`. Here z is not a variable. It is the output of a summation op that i a tensor. Tensorflow does not create a new variable z here.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [`tf.stop_gradient`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stop_gradient):

```
a = tf.stop_gradient(x)
```

Quoting the docs,

> This is useful any time you want to compute a value with TensorFlow but need to pretend that the value was a constant.

Comment: EXACTLY what I needed! Thanks so much!